# Broken Embed Code - rateabiz

Tags: javascript, widget, embed

I received the following Review Widget code from a client which i cannot get functioning.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(w, d) {
    w._rab_review_q = w._rab_review_q || [];

    w._rab_review_q.push({
        id: '66e0c56a275da98c80814d01513be966',
        reviewDivId: 'review-widget-container'
    });

    var el = d.createElement("script");
    el.async=true;
    el.src="//cdn.rateabiz.com/reviews/loader.js";
    el.type="text/javascript";
    var s0 = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s0.parentNode.insertBefore(el, s0);
})(window, document);
</script>
<div style="width:220px;" id="review-widget-container"></div>
```

I have tried the code on one of our development wp sites http://doctor-connect.org/about-us/ with all plugins turned off, i have also tried a straight up html page that again produces no results (http://doctor-connect.org/testing.html).

Unfortunately the client will not provide me with their account details and i cannot find any customer support info for Rateabiz.

Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

Comment: You write that you see no results.  Do you see any errors in the JavaScript console?  Does the request for loader.js return a 200, a 404, or something else?

Comment: `el.src="//cdn.rateabiz.com/reviews/loader.js";` looks fishy.  Are you sure you don't want something like `el.src="http://cdn.rateabiz.com/reviews/loader.js";`?

Comment: Thanks for the replay David. It pulls the console just fine. i did try it both ways, with and without the http: but still have the same results

Comment: Your exact snippets works perfectly fine when I run it in an empty html page, so it seems to me that there's something wrong with your wordpress setup. There are a few things you can test: 1. check if noscript/adblocker/ublock/etc is blocking the loader script. 2. Check if the code is actually inserted in the page. 3. Check if the loader script is loaded. It most likely goes wrong on one of these 3 points.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example of a currently working model if it helps. Key things I see different are that the template: 'dark' or template: 'light' is missing and that the el.src='.....' are different. Please see the working code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    (function(w, d){                                    
        w._rab_review_q = w._rab_review_q || []; 

        w._rab_review_q.push({
            id: '7b258b0c5ec39fc7b15eaf390c70d1b7', 
            reviewDivId: 'review-widget-container', 
            template: 'dark'
        }); 

        var el = d.createElement("script"); 
        el.async=true; 
        el.src="//s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.rateabiz.com/reviews/loader.js"; 
        el.type="text/javascript"; 
        var s0 = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; 
        s0.parentNode.insertBefore(el, s0);
    })(window, document);
</script>
```